# change the time interval in spring app using the code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, localdate

I have a spring boot applicate that is using many types of date objects it
like:

- java.util.Date
- java.time.LocalDate
- java.time.Instant

I have a sandbox environment, I want to do some tests on it,
but in tests, I need time to be changed by shifting the current_time by one year, in other words, I want to interval the time by 1 year.

example:
let's suppose the date now is **7/feb/2022**
if I called any date function, I need it to return **7/feb/2023**,

I want to change the date just in the spring app, I don't want to change the whole server time.

Is this doable in spring app for any of the previous date objects?

---

***update:***
I am using code like this in all my app

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
Date date = new Date()
```

I don't want to change the code in all my app (line by line)

I am looking at changing the date by adding some configurations, not by changing the existing code.

Comment: You cannot. For javax.time you can use a `Clock` for the old `java.util` there is no other solution than to write a specialized class. So either way you need to modify your code (or change the system date).

Answer (score 0):

For *java.time* classes, you can pass an optional `Clock` argument. The `Clock` class offers several static method returning alerted clock behavior. One of those supports a fixed moment, that does not increment.

Set up your altered clock.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate aYearFromToday = LocalDate.now( zoneId ).plusYears( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = aYearFromToday.atStartOfDay( zoneId ) ;
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ; 
Clock fixedClock = Clock.fixed( instant , zoneId ) ;
```

Usage.

```
Instant nowFake = Instant.now( fixedClock ) ;
LocalDate todayFake = LocalDate.now( fixedClock ) ;
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I need to change the date as configuration for the whole app, not by changing the existing code, I have updated my question to make it more clear full.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these java objects work well with each other. I'm assuming you are storing the server time in one of these classes. There is a simple function to add a year in LocalDate. Here is what I would do to get one year after the given server time.

```
LocalDate serverDate = LocalDate.of(2022, 2, 7);
System.out.println(serverDate);

LocalDate newTestDate = serverDate.plusYears(1);
System.out.println(newTestDate);


2022-02-07
2023-02-07
```

Most of these date objects can convert into the other object with a simple function. Hope this answers your question!